# Cannot Login via SSH with LDAP-Account after changing default port

Tags: centos, ssh, ldap

I changes the ssh default port on my CentOS7 installation. But I am not able to connect to the server with an ldap-account. I am getting "connection refused and  the following error:

```
Nov 16 16:43:52 server sshd[26297]: PAM 2 more authentication failures; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=localhost
Nov 16 16:43:59 server sshd[26308]: Invalid user random2 from ::1
Nov 16 16:43:59 server sshd[26308]: input_userauth_request: invalid user random2 [preauth]
Nov 16 16:44:04 server sshd[26308]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
Nov 16 16:44:04 server sshd[26308]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=localhost
Nov 16 16:44:07 server sshd[26308]: Failed password for invalid user random2 from ::1 port 58711 ssh2
```

The firewall is shutdown and I already enabled the nondefault port.

I do not know what this "invalid user" means, because I can clearly see him.

Hopefully someone got an idea.

Thanks in advance.

most sincerely

Twinhand

Edit1:
nsswitch.conf

```
passwd:     files sss ldap
shadow:     files sss ldap
group:      files sss ldap
```

/etc/openldap/ldap.conf

```
URI ldap://servername.example.com/
BASE dc=example,dc=com
TLS_REQCERT allow
```

Edit2

```
ssh -vv -p 2431 random2@localhost
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 56: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to localhost [::1] port 2431.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: mac_setup: setup hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug2: mac_setup: setup hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org need=16 dh_need=16
debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org need=16 dh_need=16
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA 
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
debug1: Host '[localhost]:2431' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa ((nil)),
debug2: key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil)),
debug2: key: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil)),
debug2: key: /root/.ssh/id_ed25519 ((nil)),
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: Next authentication method: password
random2@localhost's password: 
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
Permission denied, please try again.
random2@localhost's password:
```

Edit 2:

```
Nov 18 17:30:01 peacock systemd: Created slice user-0.slice.
Nov 18 17:30:01 peacock systemd: Starting Session 329 of user root.
Nov 18 17:30:01 peacock systemd: Started Session 329 of user root.
Nov 18 17:30:01 peacock nslcd[2917]: [45d5c5] <passwd="root"> ldap_result() failed: No such object
Nov 18 17:30:01 peacock nslcd[2917]: [16f79a] <group/member="root"> ldap_result() failed: No such object
Nov 18 17:30:01 peacock nslcd[2917]: [16f79a] <group/member="root"> ldap_result() failed: No such object
Nov 18 17:30:01 peacock nslcd[2917]: [c8c7c2] <group/member="gdm"> ldap_result() failed: No such object
Nov 18 17:30:01 peacock nslcd[2917]: [c8c7c2] <group/member="gdm"> ldap_result() failed: No such object
Nov 18 17:30:01 peacock nslcd[2917]: [f31d87] <group/member="gdm"> ldap_result() failed: No such object
```

What in the world is this? My whole /var/log/messages is full of that.

Comment: These are failed attempts to connect to LDAP server. You can find clues trying to connect via command line using ldapsearch: `ldapsearch -x -LLL -E pr=100/noprompt -H ldap://host:port -D "CN=xxx,OU=xxx,DC=xxx,DC=xxx,DC=xxx" -w "passwd" -b "DC=xxx,DC=xxx" "(name=*)" name`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to authenticate using local passwd file instead LDAP server.

On the client machine check:

- /etc/ldap.conf and /etc/openldap/ldap.conf --> LDAP server and base search must be properly defined.
- /etc/nsswitch.conf --> Search *passwd, group and shadow* definitions. They must include "ldap":

> ```
> passwd:         ldap compat  
> group:          ldap compat  
> shadow:         ldap compat
> ```

Increasing verbosity helps a lot. Connect using -v -vv -vvv switches and look for authentication info:

```
ssh -vv user@host
```

Comment: I added the contents of the asked files above. There is no /etc/ldap.conf But a /etc/sudo-ldap.conf.

Comment: @Twinhand: Could you post a "ssh -vv user@host" trace? There must be some clue we can see increasing verbosity.

Comment: Has been edited above.

Comment: if you are using centos 7, try to use only sssd and don't mixed with legacy way, you need to work with sssd.conf

Comment: There is also no sssd.conf at least im not able to find it. I also cannot remeber to accualy have used it on the last installtion. I already set it up once, but than it got hacked and I did it the exact same way as I did on the first installation, but than this happends. I can perfectly see the created users of the ldap server in my phpldapadmin but i just cannot figure out, why the system is not using it.

Answer (score 0):

Well this is not really a solution, but it worked out somehow. As I tried different things yesterday to fix this issue, I accidentally deleted /etc with my server killed, nevertheless I just reinstalled it from the scratch. And setup slapd in the EXACT same way with THE SAME files and THE SAME procedure. And it worked. I do not know what the problem was, but thanks for you help anyway.